# Implementing a WCF SOAP service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, soap

I've implemented a C# WCF soap service which is going to be consumed by a single asynchronous client. Does my WCF service need to be asynchronous as well?

This WCF soap service methods are consuming another soap service(DSGSampleService is a web reference to that soap service).I do not have specification if that service is sync or async). Here is just a sample.

```
namespace RdvRTA_Sample
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            DSGSampleService.PaymentAPIService proxy = new DSGSampleService.PaymentAPIService();
            DSGSampleService.GenerateTransactionToken gtt = new DSGSampleService.GenerateTransactionToken();
            DSGSampleService.GenerateTransactionTokenResponse gttr = proxy.generateTransactionToken(gtt);

        }
    }
}
```

If no, then would there be any performance difference if my web service is async.

Comment: If the client uses the "Add Service Reference" feature then the options in that dialog allow you to generate Task Based Operations that can be awaited.

Comment: I'll be hosting it on IIS, so shouldn't IIS handle the threading in this case?

Comment: Threading happens on the client. All web requests can be async regardless of the server side implementation. You could just use HttpClient to make the call but then you have a bunch of messy soap to deal with. Adding service reference generates client-side code that is async.